# How to fix failing the sync project with Gradle files?

Tags: android-studio

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Invalid revision: 3.22.1-g37088a8-dirty

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 54s
Invalid revision: 3.22.1-g37088a8-dirty
`

I am using 3.1.2 version of android studio software. gradle version is 4.6. I am getting above error when I going to build the project. I tried change the gradle version to 4.4 too in gradle-wrapper.properties file. But anything didn't work. Can anyone have any solution as well as a reason why this happen?

As well as i have not set gradle in environment >> system variable. Because I thougtht It is installing to project from android studio. (Please tell something if there any wrong)